# Wrong day of the week returned by date in PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have the following data coming out of `date_parse`:

```
$date_array['year'] = '2015';
$date_array['month'] = '4';
$date_array['day'] = '25';
```

I am trying to get the day of the week for this specific date:

```
echo date('w',strtotime($date_array['day'] . " " . $date_array['month'] . " " . $date_array['year']));
```

This returns `4`, which is the code for Thursday, while that day was a Saturday, so I am expecting a `6`. I have also tried reordering the elements withing `strtotime` thinking it might have something to do with my time zone settings, but I am still getting `4` as the result.

Comment: Worth having a look at the supported [formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) for `strtotime`.

Comment: 25th of April 2015 was on Saturday...

Comment: @JanChimiak yeah right xD I'll update the question.

Comment: It's interesting that some online calendars got it wrong... Compare http://www.calendar-365.com/calendar/2015/april.html and http://www.calendar-365.co.uk/calendar/2015/April.html I actually double-checked my wall calendar...

Comment: On my computer (could be locale based) strtotime is returning false, so you're getting the day of the week for the Unix Epoch, which was a Thursday.

Comment: @JanChimiak No they are both right, it's just that one starts the week on Sunday and the other on Monday :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) does not recognize the [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) `DD MM YYYY` you used; you could use international format (`YYYY-MM-DD`), or european (`DD-MM-YYYY`) or american (`MM/DD/YYYY`) instead.

For example:

```
echo date('w', strtotime("$date_array[year]-$date_array[month]-$date_array[day]"));
```

is `6`, which is saturday and is correct.

Comment: I have decided to accept this answer because it also explained *why* things were not working. Upvoted all other answers too.

Comment: Ok, but I recommend `mktime()` because you avoid this kind of errors (this was my explanation)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this way:

```
 $d = $date_array;
 date("w", mktime(0, 0, 0, $d['month'], $d['day'], $d['year']));
```

I use `mktime()` because it works perfectly as you'll get a correct timestamp. This code prints `6` that's the correct day.

Note that since PHP 5.1.0 you can use `L`  parameter to get the days from 1 (monday) to 7 (sunday) in a more logic human beings way.

```
 date("L", mktime(0, 0, 0, $d['month'], $d['day'], $d['year']));
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

have a look on below code:

```
$date_array = array();
$date_array['year'] = '2015';
$date_array['month'] = '04';
$date_array['day'] = '25';

$d = $date_array;

echo date('w-L-D',strtotime($date_array['year']."-".$date_array['month'] . "-" . $date_array['day']));//output: 6-0-Sat
```

For more detail on format have alook at [PHP: date - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)